# Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, segmentation-fault

The link between simulator and xamarin stops after a few seconds (simulator is white) and im able to push the play button again. I use `Xamarin.Forms` for this iOS project. I've tried this in the newest versions for both Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio.

Native stacktrace:

```
2017-09-13 14:22:34.113 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   0   NewsTestOne.iOS                     0x0000000106847184
mono_handle_native_crash + 244
2017-09-13 14:22:34.113 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   1   NewsTestOne.iOS                     0x000000010685320b mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 171
2017-09-13 14:22:34.114 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000010d451b3a _sigtramp + 26
2017-09-13 14:22:34.114 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   3   ???                                 0x0003f78b358d56aa 0x0 + 1116602201101994
2017-09-13 14:22:34.114 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   4   CFNetwork                           0x000000010bc51e2e _ZN15TCPIOConnection16_startConnectionEv + 530
2017-09-13 14:22:34.114 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   5   CFNetwork                           0x000000010bd8e32a ___ZN4Tube23_onqueue_prepConnectionEU13block_pointerFvvEU13block_pointerFviE_block_invoke.67 + 726
2017-09-13 14:22:34.114 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   6   CFNetwork                           0x000000010bd8e807 ___ZN4Tube23_onqueue_prepConnectionEU13block_pointerFvvEU13block_pointerFviE_block_invoke_2.83 + 21
2017-09-13 14:22:34.115 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0ae585 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
2017-09-13 14:22:34.115 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0cf792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
2017-09-13 14:22:34.115 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0b5237 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1022
2017-09-13 14:22:34.115 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0b598f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1053
2017-09-13 14:22:34.115 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0b7899 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 813
2017-09-13 14:22:34.116 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d0b750d _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
2017-09-13 14:22:34.116 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d4635a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
2017-09-13 14:22:34.116 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical:   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010d46307d start_wqthread + 13
2017-09-13 14:22:34.116 NewsTestOne.iOS[25106:19993674] critical: 

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 5):

This usually indicate thread errors on your code, I suggest you debug all your server side calls which are asynchronous, it can be plenty of things like:

- A `Task.Run` method running in a background thread trying to update a UI property.
- A `Custom Renderer` or a `Dependency Service`which is using within an asynchronous Task.
- If you have Timers in your code take a looks at those also.

With the latest versions of Xamarin the debugger is not capable to correctly debug native code so make sure you clean your solution and try to debug on a real device. (also getting rid of break points sometime helps.)